# Notification couldn't disappear after click, and Notification setAutoCancel(true) doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications

Notification couldn't disappear after click, and Notification setAutoCancel(true) doesn't work. The following is my code:

```
NotificationManager notifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .setContentTitle("New Message")
                                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                                .setContentText("New Question")
                                .setAutoCancel(true);
                        notifyManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `setContentIntent()`:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent(), 0);
NotificationManager notifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                    .setContentTitle("New Message")
                                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                                    .setContentText("New Question")
                                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                    .setAutoCancel(true);
                            notifyManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```